# From regular JS loops to Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to turn some JS regular loops into lodash but I am getting the following error

> TypeError: key.indexOf is not a function

here works properly

```
        $scope.rows.forEach(function(row) {
          for (var key in row) {
            if (key.indexOf('XX') === 0) {
              var value = row[key];
              if (value) {
                row[key] = $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
              }
            }
          }
        });
```

and with this way the error comes up

```
        _.forEach($scope.rows, function(row) {
          _.forEach(row, function(key) {
            if (key.indexOf('XX') === 0) {
              var value = row[key];
              if (value) {
                row[key] = $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
              }
            }                
          });
        });
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_.forEach` calls the function with `(value, key, collection)`. Use it this way:

```
_.forEach(row, function(value, key) {
    if (key.indexOf('XX') === 0) {
    ...
```